# extracting src and paste before in html link with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to extract the src of an img and then paste the src into a "a href" to wrap around the original img

I have two versions that I've messed with and can't get either to work. I think one of my problems seems to be inserting an "a href" before or around an element.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var x = hdnImg.children('img').attr('src') 

  $( "img" ).wrap(function() {
  return "<a href='" +x+ "' class="anyclass"></a>";
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var p = hdnImg.children('img').attr('src')

  $( "img" ).before( "<a href='#' class="anyclass">" );
  $( "img" ).after( "</a>" );
</script>
```

ultimately, this is was I'm trying to go for:

html before script:

```
    <img src="http://a.jpg">
    <img src="http://b.jpg">
```

html after script

```
    <a hre="http://a.jpg" class="classy"><img src="http://a.jpg"></a>
    <a hre="http://b.jpg" class="classy"><img src="http://b.jpg"></a>
```

I'm still learning javascript and could use a little guidance. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
$( "img" ).each(function() {
    var x = $(this).attr('src'); 
    $(this).wrap( "<a href='" +x+ "' class='anyclass'></a>");
});
```

Comment: perfect. when is it necessary to start this off with a $(document).ready(function () {

Comment: You'll want to put it in a $(document).ready(function () {}); to make sure the img elements exist before you wrap them.

Comment: can I limit this to only grabbing the images inside a div by changing the first section to (".class img"). At the moment I'm affecting other img elements that I hadn't considered and want to contain this a little.

Comment: Yes you can. You can also add some specific class to these images and use $('.someClass').each

Answer (score 1):

```
$('img').each(function(index,ele) {
    $(this).wrap('<a href="' + $(ele).attr('src') + '" class="classy"></a>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/AWeAu/

Answer (score 0):

maybe this can help you.

```
$("img").addClass("classy");
$("img").html('<img src="http://b.jpg">');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this will be help you

HTML

```
 <img src="http://a.jpg">
    <img src="http://b.jpg">
        <div></div>
        <input type='button' value='Click Me'/>
```

JS

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    $('img').each(function(){
        var item='New: <a href='+$(this).prop('src')+' class="classy"><img src='+$(this).prop('src')+' ></a>';
    $(this).remove();
    $('div').append(item);
    });
});
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/subhash9/CsAfJ/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="images">
   <span><img src="http://a.jpg"></span>
   <span><img src="http://b.jpg"></span>
</div>
```

Use the following script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.images img').each(function () {

            var link = "<a href='" + $(this).attr("src") + "'>" + $(this).closest('span').html() + "</a>";
            $(this).closest('span').html(link);
        });
    });
```